# How do i get rotation data from HEIF format?

Tags: android, exif, heif

HEIF foramt supported Android PIe(9.0)

I was got image(jpg, png) rotation data with ExifInterface.

but HEIF format not provide rotataion data.

how do i get data?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: https://www.androidcentral.com/android-p-features-we-love-hdr-and-heif-support / The article found that the HEIF format has its own rotation data. But I don't know how to bring this information programmatically. I'd really appreciate your help.